# Helloworld c++ makefile in FreeBSD

Tags: c++, makefile, clang, freebsd

Trying to compile my first c++ program using `PMAKE` (default FreeBSD make).

**helloworld.cpp**:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {

        std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
        std::cin.get();
}
```

**makefile**:

```
OBJS    = helloworld.o
CFLAGS  = -Wall -Werror -std=c++14

helloworld      : $(OBJS)
        cc $(.ALLSRC) -o $(.TARGET)

helloworld.o    : helloworld.cpp
        cc -c helloworld.cpp
```

**output**

```
$make
cc helloworld.o -o helloworld
ld: error: undefined symbol: std::__1::cout
>>> referenced by helloworld.cpp
>>>               helloworld.o:(main)

ld: error: undefined symbol: std::__1::cin
>>> referenced by helloworld.cpp
>>>               helloworld.o:(main)

ld: error: undefined symbol: std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::get()
>>> referenced by helloworld.cpp
>>>               helloworld.o:(main)

ld: error: undefined symbol: std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::put(char)
>>> referenced by helloworld.cpp
>>>               helloworld.o:(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&))

ld: error: undefined symbol: std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::flush()
>>> referenced by helloworld.cpp
>>>               helloworld.o:(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&))

ld: error: undefined symbol: std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)
>>> referenced by helloworld.cpp
>>>               helloworld.o:(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long))

ld: error: undefined symbol: std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::~sentry()
>>> referenced by helloworld.cpp
>>>               helloworld.o:(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long))
>>> referenced by helloworld.cpp
>>>               helloworld.o:(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long))

ld: error: undefined symbol: __cxa_begin_catch
>>> referenced by helloworld.cpp
>>>               helloworld.o:(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long))
>>> referenced by helloworld.cpp
>>>               helloworld.o:(__clang_call_terminate)

ld: error: undefined symbol: std::__1::ios_base::__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrow()
>>> referenced by helloworld.cpp
>>>               helloworld.o:(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long))

ld: error: undefined symbol: __cxa_end_catch
>>> referenced by helloworld.cpp
>>>               helloworld.o:(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long))
>>> referenced by helloworld.cpp
>>>               helloworld.o:(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long))

ld: error: undefined symbol: std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()
>>> referenced by helloworld.cpp
>>>               helloworld.o:(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char))
>>> referenced by helloworld.cpp
>>>               helloworld.o:(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char))

ld: error: undefined symbol: std::terminate()
>>> referenced by helloworld.cpp
>>>               helloworld.o:(__clang_call_terminate)

ld: error: undefined symbol: std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(unsigned long, char)
>>> referenced by helloworld.cpp
ld: error: undefined symbol: std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(unsigned long, char)
>>> referenced by helloworld.cpp
>>>               helloworld.o:(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string(unsigned long, char))

ld: error: undefined symbol: std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const
>>> referenced by helloworld.cpp
>>>               helloworld.o:(std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const)

ld: error: undefined symbol: std::__1::locale::~locale()
>>> referenced by helloworld.cpp
>>>               helloworld.o:(std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const)
>>> referenced by helloworld.cpp
>>>               helloworld.o:(std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const)

ld: error: undefined symbol: std::__1::ctype<char>::id
>>> referenced by helloworld.cpp
>>>               helloworld.o:(std::__1::ctype<char> const& std::__1::use_facet<std::__1::ctype<char> >(std::__1::locale const&))

ld: error: undefined symbol: std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const
>>> referenced by helloworld.cpp
>>>               helloworld.o:(std::__1::ctype<char> const& std::__1::use_facet<std::__1::ctype<char> >(std::__1::locale const&))

ld: error: undefined symbol: std::__1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)
>>> referenced by helloworld.cpp
>>>               helloworld.o:(std::__1::ios_base::setstate(unsigned int))

ld: error: undefined symbol: __gxx_personality_v0
>>> referenced by helloworld.cpp
>>>               helloworld.o:(.eh_frame+0x4AB)
cc: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation
```

I am using `FreeBSD 12.2` which defaults `clang 10.0.1`.

Note: `cc -o helloworld helloworld.cpp` does not work either.

The question is probably very basic but I am still stuck.

Comment: Try using `c++` (or`clang++`) instead. It will link with the C++ standard library automatically.

Comment: By doing that (using `c++`), it works. Is that how makefiles are expected to be used? I mean using `c++` instead of `cc`? Could I also link the C++ standard library manually in the makefile? (to understand better the linking process)

Comment: If you compile C++ code you are expected to use the `c++` command, if you compile C code you should use `cc` command. Then, to link, if any of your source files uses C++, use `c++`, if all are C use `cc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C and C++ are two different languages. Use a C++ compiler to compile C++. In your case, the C++ compiler is probably called `c++`, not `cc`.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend to just use [CMake](https://cmake.org/) so just create a file named `CMakeLists.txt` with this content

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(helloworld)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} helloworld.cpp )
set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)
```

Then just can compile your code on every OS including BSD with

```
mkdir bin
cd bin
cmake ..
cmake -build .
```